# Wordpress | Need to refresh page to see changes on wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, caching

everytime when i make a change in Wordpress (wp-admin) i need to refresh the page to see the effect of the change. Is there a solution so i dont need to refresh the page everytime?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is is your changing?

Comment: @Dan i change the post title and it doesnt show the new post title in the backend only when i CTRL f5

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue? I bumped into it myself today on a fresh installation of wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

In most likelihood, this is a (local) browser problem.

To quickly confirm this, try in a different browser. If that works, try clearing the cache + cookies (on the problematic browser) and restarting the browser and/or the PC.

If that doesn't work, try updating the browser to the latest version. If that fails too, try uninstalling and re-installing the browser. In all cases, make sure JavaScript support is fully available for your browser.

Comment: it is not a local problem i work at a company we all 4 have the problem.